# Creating a dynamic iframe shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am attempting to add an iframe to my wordpress site with a dynamic url that is saved to the individual post using advanced custom fields.  The field name is `raw_iframe_url` and it contains the URL for the iframe.

In order to add this to my site, I am creating a shortcode that simply outputs the iframe but I cannot get it working.  So far I have this:

```
function load_3d_tour_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $iframe_url = get_field('raw_embed_url'); // returns the URL
    echo '<iframe src="' . $iframe_url . '"><iframe>';
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/: _“Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce an output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode.”_

Answer (score 0):

I see that maybe this isn't the intended use, but this solution worked just fine:

```
function load_3d_tour_shortcode( $atts ) {
  $iframe_url = get_field('raw_embed_url'); // returns the URL
  return '<iframe src="'.$field_URL.'" height="450" style="width:100%;"></iframe>';
}
```